# Parsing XML using XDocument - vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

Can I get some help parsing the "node"'s from the following xml using XDocument? I want to return the result of each "node" in an array of xXMLNode. After a few hours im not abled to solve my problem myself.

```
Public Structure xXMLNode
   Dim _name() As String
   Dim _value() As String
End Structure

Public Function XMLRead(_file As String) As xXMLNode()
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <node>
    <Username>uknwn1447</Username>
    <Password>MineCraftXxghx</Password>
    <Enabled>YezSir</Enabled>
  </node>
  <node>
    <Username>loluu</Username>
    <Password>D4ddy</Password>
    <Enabled>N0pe</Enabled>
  </node>
</root>
```

Comment: So you want all nodes into an array ***or*** do you want to get a list of the nodes into an object that you can do something with?

Answer (score 0):

The way to parse out this using the document model is like this:

```
Sub MyRead(strXML As String)

    Dim xDom As New XmlDocument

    xDom.LoadXml(strXML)

    Dim MyNodeList As XmlNodeList

    MyNodeList = xDom.SelectNodes("/root/node")

    Dim MyNode As XmlNode

    For Each MyNode In MyNodeList
        Debug.Print(MyNode.Item("Username").InnerText)
        Debug.Print(MyNode.Item("Password").InnerText)
        Debug.Print(MyNode.Item("Enabled").InnerText)
    Next

End Sub
```

Output:

```
uknwn1447
MineCraftXxghx
YezSir

loluu
D4ddy
N0pe
```

You could certainly modify the above to return the nodeList. I also used a few extra lines in my declare statements - the above could be somewhat shorter, but for clarity and to outline the actual data type declares, the above should get you started.